# Issues with iv_robust command in R - fixed effects

Tags: r

I am having problems making my iv_robust function work (from the `estimatr` package). Basically, I am trying to find a way to replicate the `xtivreg2 Stata` function in R as this also takes into account fixed effects, but as soon as I specify that I would like to include to fixed effects to account for the lagged variables I get the following error message: `"Error in list() : could not find function "list""` This only happens when I include the `fixed_effects=TRUE` option. Without it, it works just fine. Any idea on why this is the case? And what I could do to fix it?

Many thanks. Hope this is clear - first question/contribution in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at `help(iv_robust)` before trying to use it to make sure you have the syntax correct.

In this case, the way to specify fixed effects is by telling it the variable(s) you want to have fixed effects for. So if you wanted ID fixed effects and Year fixed effects, for example, `fixed_effects = ~ID+Year`.

Unlike Stata, `estimatr` doesn't really declare things as panel data like `xtset` does in Stata. So it will have no idea which variable is your ID variable unless you tell it. That's why it's not set up to accept an option like `fixed_effects = TRUE`.

There are packages that declare panel data in a similar way to Stata: `plm`, `tsibble`, `panelr`, and `pmdplyr`. But I don't believe any of these have a panel IV function (I think, I haven't checked).

Comment: `plm` does have instrumental variable estimators for panel data.